# Jquery ajax method request body is null but postman is working normal

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, mule, httplistener

I am configuring a service on Mule ESB to feed the interface that i've been working on with jQuery and jQuery UI.

Mule ESB contains a http listener whose method is "POST" to get request body and evaluate it then give necessary response.

Here is my request that i am sending via POSTMAN :

```
var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "http://localhost:8081/feed",
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
  },
  "processData": false,
  "data": "{\r\n\t\"vibs\": [\r\n\t\t\"TAS2002\"\r\n\t],\r\n\t\"language\": \"de-DE\"\r\n}"
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

Mule ESB and web application runs in different web hosts(web server for Mule, node http-server for web-app) and i know that this is effecting to cross domain policy... But i don't know how i should configure my service to handle this request.

Mule always get the request with null body, because normally when i was sending same request via POSTMAN, postman transfers request's body into [#message.payload] object.

When i am trying with jQuery ajax or javascript XHR etc. , on debugger it shows that request payload is null. So i can't evaluate request body...

Could anyone help me about how to solve the issue ?

By the way i am using Mule ESB 3.7.0 for server runtime, and jQuery 1.10.2 to use ajax.

Any help would be appreciated, many thanks in advance!

Comment: The data you're sending doesn't look like valid json - maybe remove all the newline characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with following code

```
var settings = {
    "async": true,
    "crossDomain": true,
    "url": "http://localhost:8081/feed",
    "method": "POST",
    "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    "cache-control" : "no-cache",
    "processData": false,
    "data": "{\r\n\t\"vibs\": [\r\n\t\t\"TAS2002\"\r\n\t],\r\n\t\"language\":      \"de-DE\"\r\n}"
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
   console.log(response);
});
```

When used `"headers": {
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
  },`

I was getting log as 
 No listener found for request: (OPTIONS)/feed

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello, actually the error was related to this field. I directly got the code what POSTMAN is generated for me. So thank you for your answer.